# Regex pattern for house letter

Tags: c#, regex

Im' looking for a Regex pattern that finds a house letter.

Eks(looking for the letter d).

```
1. Streetname 3d, 7000 Town Country. 
2. Streetname 3 d, 7000 Town Country. 
3. Streetname 13d, 7000 Town Country. 
4. Streetname 13 d, 7000 Town Country.
```

I'm writing i C#.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? Protip™: use [regexpal.com](http://www.regexpal.com)

Comment: I would probably not use a regex, rather some string method to find the rightmost letter before the comma. E.g. split using comma, then find the rightmost letter immediately before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this pattern works in your 4 cases.
  I don't test the code but just try it and tell me.

```
string sPattern = "[a-zA-Z 0-9]*([a-zA-Z]),.*";
int i = 0;
foreach (string s in address)
{
     Match m = Regex.Match(s, sPattern);
     if (m.Success){
         houseLetter[i] = m.ToString(); 
     } else {
         houseLetter[i] = "Not Found";
     }
     i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some combination of:

```
const string address = "Streetname 3d, 7000 Town Country";
string streetPart = address.Split(',')[0];
char letter = streetPart[streetPart.Length - 1];
bool isLetter = char.IsLetter(letter);
Debug.WriteLine("{0}, isLetter: {1}", letter, isLetter);
```

will probably work...

Outputs: `d, isLetter: true`

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking that there is a regex that will universally solve this problem, stop thinking it. With your scheme my parents' street address would be

```
Ioakim 3rd 4242, 7000 Town Country    // "Ioakim 3rd" is the street name
```

As you see, you are definitely going to have some percentage of wrong results. Are your four examples the only cases where you need guaranteed correct results?

Comment: Now I can stalk your parents. Weird address by the way.

Comment: @Cicada: Unusual, true. Imagine you live in Paris and you have streets named after the various Louises -- your will need some numeral to differentiate their names. That's where the "3rd" comes from.

Comment: Im' only gonna use it for norwegian adresses, and we don't use 3rd :P

Comment: @GoldnArms: That's an unimportant detail. My counter-question stands: are those four examples the only ones you need to guarantee correct operation on?